# R: sentiment analysis using Azure Cognitive Service Text API and HTTR package

Tags: r, azure, sentiment-analysis, azure-cognitive-services, httr

I have problem with connection to the Azure Cognitive Service Text API ([here is documentation:](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9)) using HTTR.

```
library(httr)
library("XML")
api_url <- 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment'

mybody <-list('id'='1', 'text'= 'come on love boy', 'language'="en")


result = POST(api_url,body = mybody, content_type('application/json'),encode = "json", add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"='application/json',"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"="XXX")))
result
Response [https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment]
  Date: 2019-02-21 00:12
###correct status = 200
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 222 B
```

How shall I implement "text" into the body of the API query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

write the body as:

```
mybody <-list('documents'= list(list('id'='1', 'text'= 'come on love boy', 'language'="en")))
```

Works.